# Redirección 301 de una url con variables dinámicas

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirección

en mi página tengo dos buscadores, uno que utilizaba para la página principal y otro para el contenido del post_type.

Decidí mover la página del post_type a la página principal y los artículos que eran de la página principal a una página que llamé blog; por ende tuve que hacer la redirección de los resultados de búsqueda de la página principal para que se muestren en el directorio "blog", de tal manera que la url se mostraría algo como:

```
/blog/?s=variable
```

Ahora, los resultados del post_type también se están mostrando dentro del directorio "blog" y quiero que los resultados del post_type se muestren en el directorio "library", la url ahora se ve así:

```
/blog/?s=variable&post_type=library
```

y quiero que sea vea así:

```
/library/?s=variable&post_type=library
```

He utilizado el siguiente código:

```
RewriteRule ^s=(.*)%&post_type%=library$ https://www.cyberdocentes.com/library/$1 [R=301,L]
```

También utilicé este:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)%&post_type=library$ 
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.cyberdocentes.com/library/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Y algo como esto:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)%&post_type%=library$ https://www.cyberdocentes.com/library/$1
```

He realizado algunas variaciones a dichos códigos conforme he ido investigando pero ninguno me ha funcionado hasta el momento, espero que me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 4):

Ya solucioné la redirección.

Para redireccionar los resultados búsqueda de post_type a la página "library":

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)&post_type=library$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.cyberdocentes.com/library/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Y para redireccionar los resultados de búsqueda de artículos a la página de "blog":

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.cyberdocentes.com/blog/?s=%1 [L=301,R]
```

Si tienen una mejor solución, espero me ayuden, muchas gracias.